# VMware - Create VM out of a current desktop

Tags: vmware-workstation

is there any tools available that i can run on a desktop to create a complete copy of it that i can use to run in VMWare Workstation 6.5?

Also I did use the import feature to do it to one desktop but because if goes over the network it took approx 7 hours to complete.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. [VMware vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/)

Answer (score 4):

As an update to this, Workstation 8 comes with a P to V converter

Comment: Aww Sweet! Didn't know that/

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can image the disk, use the Qemu tool qemu-img to convert it to a VMware disk file:

```
qemu-img convert -f raw raw.img -O vmdk new.vmdk
```

And that's basically it.